# Sphinx autodoc dies on ImportError of third party package

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

There's any way to exclude the import part of a module and then document it with sphinx-python?
I have a module that imports another package (other different project) and then the sphinx gives this error:

> """
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 321, in import_object
>       **import**(self.modname)
>     File "/home/x/GitHub/project/mod_example1.py", line 33, in 
>       from other_pck import Klass, KlassStuff
>   ImportError: No module named other_pck
>   """

And if I comment the import parts in the module that calls/imports that package the sphinx can do the autodoc.
I tried with all the sphinx autodoc modules: autoclass, automodule, etc... but the result is always the same once it try's to import the other package.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are fixing the issue wrong way. The correct way to fix the issue is to make Sphinx aware of your existing other packages as autodoc functionality **must** import Python packages to scan the source code. Python packages cannot be imported without all their dependencies resolved and you cannot cherry-pick lines of source code out of it, because this is how Python is built(*)

Possible solutions are

- Creating a Python virtualenv environment where both Sphinx and the other packages reside, so that they can see each other http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/
- Setting PYTHONPATH environment variable or editing sys.path in Sphinx config file, so that missing packages are added in the import list when Sphinx is run http://scienceoss.com/minimal-sphinx-setup-for-autodocumenting-python-modules/

*) In theory you can, but this is outside the scope of Sphinx and this question

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
This somehow solves my problem locally, but still remains in readthedocs. I use the requirements.txt but it doesn't get and install the other project to the virtualenv correctly. Maybe it's something with readthedocs.
Bests

Comment: I suggest ask help on #readthedocs IRC channel on freenode network

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's due to the machine that you're using to generating docs does not have the *third party* package imported by the python project. For example, there isn't `pytorch` on my current machine to write the docs. You can **mock the required packages by adding the following in `conf.py`**

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['packages', 'to', 'mock']
```

In my case, its

```
autodoc_mock_imports = ['torch']
```

See [this blog](https://brendanhasz.github.io/2019/01/05/sphinx.html#automodule-and-autoclass) for detail.