# make packages installed in virtualenv visibile to sphinx

Tags: virtualenv, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using `sphinx` to document my software. and I am using a `virtualenv` for the installation. now some packages are only installed in the virtual environment, and sphinx does not see them.

I have this code in my `conf.py`:

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
p = os.path.abspath('..')
sys.path.insert(0, p)
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    q = os.sep.join([os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'],
                     'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages'])
    sys.path.insert(0, q)
    p = p + ":" + q

os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = p
```

yet if I `make html`, I get this sort of warnings:

```
/home/mario/Local/github/Bauble/bauble.classic/doc/api.rst:358: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class u'TagItemGUI' from module u'bauble.plugins.tag'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/mario/Local/github/Bauble/bauble.classic/bauble/plugins/tag/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import *
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

my `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages` contains `SQLAlchemy-1.0.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg`.

definitely related to question [Sphinx autodoc dies on ImportError of third party package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088792), but the description of the procedure I chose to follow is in a broken link.

Comment: I am now putting all in the same virtual environment, I put sphinx in its own virtual environment and then install all projects I want to document in that environment as well. but this sounds like an ugly workaround to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that packages are not directly included in virtualenv's `site-packages` dir, you would need to specify the full path to be able to import package from there. I use the following hack:

```
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    site_packages_glob = os.sep.join([
        os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'],
        'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages', 'projectname-*py2.7.egg'])
    site_packages = glob.glob(site_packages_glob)[-1]
    sys.path.insert(0, site_packages)
```

Where `projectname` is the name of the python module I would like to import.

Note that this is error prone, especially when you have multiple versions
of the module, but so far it works for me.